# array JS not showing any output, function is wrong i think

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the question,

1 - 5 is in array,

so if i input 1,
then, the number 1 is excluded from the output,

and 2-5 will automatically add up to give the number 14

2 + 3 + 4 + 5

and so on...

I have done the code but when i clicked the button add, nothing happens. Any help is appreciated.

Sorry if i'm a beginner.

```js
function add() {
  var array = ["1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5"];
    var input = document.getElementById("number");
    var output = document.getElementById("total");
output.value = "";

     for(var input in array)
     {
       if (input = 1)
       {
         output.value = 2 + 3 + 4 + 5;
       }
if (input = 2)
{
output.value = 1 + 3 + 4 + 5;
}
if (input = 3)
{
output.value = 1 + 2 + 4 + 5;

     }
     if (input = 4)
    {
      output.value = 1 + 2 + 3 + 5;
}
elseif (input = 5)

{

output.value = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4;
}
}
```

```html
</html> -->

<head>
    <body>
        <script src = "1.js"></script>
                Exclude your number:
                <br>
                <input id="number">
                <br>
                <button onClick="add();">Add!</button>
                <br>
                <br>
                Output:
                <br>
                <input id="Total">

    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: This is really not how you're expected to do it. Hint: `1+2+3+4+5` is a constant, the only changing thing is what you have to substract from that.

Comment: Get a linter! `if (input = 1)` <--- wrong

Comment: Unless the homework problem states it should be done like that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so right off the bat there are a couple of things that need to be fixed.

1. Your if statements are incorrect, when making a comparison you need to use == or ===, = is an assignment operator. When you do 'if (input = 1)', you're actually assigning the input variable a value of 1, and not checking if input is equal to 1.
2. Your id for output in html is different from what you're getting from in your function. The id is case sensitive.
3. You're trying to check if the values in the array are equal to the numbers 1,2,3,4 and 5, but you defined them as a string, like "1", "2", etc. Which will actually work in js if you use the ==, but in almost every other language it will not. For your program you should be using ===, and changing the values in your array to numbers. Ex: [1,2,3,4,5]
4. elseif should be written as else if.
5. If you try to run the code snippet it tells your that there are Syntax errors, make sure you are checking those and trying to figure out where your code went wrong.

I would recommend trying to follow some tutorials that make simple apps using js and html on YouTube and then coming back to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to loop through the array and just add that to a sum, skipping the omitted number.

```
    let sum = 0;
        for(var value in array)
        {
            if (value !== input)
            {
                sum += value;
            }
        }
    output.value = sum;
```